# Microcausality for Dirac's current

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, causality, dirac-matrices

I`m supposed to show as an exercises that for the Dirac field's associated current:

$$j^\mu=\bar{\Psi}\gamma^\mu\Psi$$

The microcausality relation holds:

$$ [j^\mu(x),j^\nu(y)]=0 \text{ for } (x-y)^2<0$$

I've worked out the commutator above until I reach the expression bellow:

$$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\bar{\Psi}(x)\Psi(x)\bar{\Psi}(y)\Psi(y)-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu\bar{\Psi}(y)\Psi(y)\bar{\Psi}(x)\Psi(x)$$

**Question:** Am I in the right track? Any obvious reason for this to be zero exploiting that the space-time interval is spacelike.

**I`m using (+,-,-,-)

Comment: Question: how did you move the $\gamma$'s past the $\Psi$'s?

Comment: Actually I`m not very confident in the way I manipulated this guys. What I did was basically consider gammas and psi's as operators in a large tensor product space, each one acting in different subspaces. Then I just used commutator properties. In that manner I treated them as commuting but I guess this might be wrong. How should I manipulate it properly?

Comment: The $\gamma$ act on the finite dimensional spin $\frac12$ representation and $\Psi$ acts both in the big Fock space *and* in the spin $\frac12$ representation. But keep it simple: $\Psi$ has spinor indices $\bar{\Psi} \gamma^\mu \Psi = \bar{\Psi}^\alpha (\gamma^\mu)^\alpha_\beta \Psi^\beta$.

Comment: I think this exercise wants you to either use microcausality of $\Psi$ or decompose in annihilation and creation operators. You'll never obtain zero identically just by manipulating the commutator.

Comment: I was thinking exactly about using microcausality for $\Psi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work out the commutator as follow:

\begin{equation}
 [j^\mu(x) , j^\nu(y) ] = [ \bar{\Psi}_\alpha(x) \gamma{^\mu}{_\alpha }{_\beta} \Psi_\beta(x) , \bar{\Psi}_\sigma(y) \gamma{^\nu}{_\sigma }{_\rho} \Psi_\rho(y)] 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \gamma{^\mu}{_\alpha }{_\beta} \gamma{^\nu}{_\sigma }{_\rho} [ \bar{\Psi}_\alpha(x) \Psi_\beta(x) , \bar{\Psi}_\sigma(y) \Psi_\rho(y)] 
\end{equation}

since $\gamma{^\mu}{_\alpha }{_\beta}$ and $\gamma{^\nu}{_\sigma }{_\rho}$ are complex numbers. Using the relations $[AB,C]=A[B,C] + [B,C]A$ and $[A,BC]=\{A,B\}C-B\{A,C\}$ and the fact that both $\bar{\Psi}$ and $\Psi$ satisfies microcauslity for a spacelike interval, you should get:

\begin{equation}
[j^\mu(x) , j^\nu(y) ] = \gamma{^\mu}{_\alpha }{_\beta} \gamma{^\nu}{_\sigma }{_\rho} [ \ \bar{\Psi}_\alpha(x) \ \{\Psi_\beta(x) , \bar{\Psi}_\sigma(y)\ \} \ \Psi_\rho(y) \  -  \ \bar{\Psi}_\sigma(y) \ \{\bar{\Psi}_\alpha(x) ,\Psi_\rho(y) \ \} \ \Psi_\beta(x) \ ]
\end{equation}

Now impose microcausality to $\bar{\Psi}$ and $\Psi$ simultaneously you  have $ \{ \bar{\Psi}_\epsilon(x) ,\Psi_\delta(y) \} = 0 $ since $(x-y)^2<0$. Then the commutator vanishes and the desired result follows.

Comment: I did it precisely in this way at the end, it went ok. Writing down the spinor indicies basically solved any confusion. Thanks though :)